# Soundtrack for Yamada-kun to 7-nin no Majo TV anime

Tags: music, merchandise, yamada-and-the-7-witches

Does anyone know who composed the original soundtrack for the TV anime "Yamada-kun to 7-nin no Majo"?

It doesn't look like it has been released on CD yet, I can't seem to find it anywhere. Can anyone tell me if there is a plan for it to be released? If so, when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDJapan seems to have the cd in stock - http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/MBR-30S

According to the webpage it was released in June.

The composer is [Masaru Yokoyama](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=67761) who has done songs for several anime series, including Freezing and Your Lie in April